# listbox and search returning null

Tags: c#, winforms, search, listbox

I have a search function which works good the first time i run it. When i try adding a new search the program shuts down giving me the error message:
"markerat = listBoxSökResultat.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower(); Object reference not set to an instance of an object. NullReference.
Ive tried using if and return; but that doesnt seem to help. Anyone knows whats wrong here?

```
private void buttonSökNamn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            var v = (from x in el.Descendants("recept")
                     where x.Element("namn").Value.ToLower().Contains(textBoxNamn.Text.ToLower())
                     select x);

            if (v == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Finns inte!");
                return;
            }

            foreach (var item in v.Elements("namn"))
            {
                Sökresultat.Add(item.Value);                
            }
            listBoxSökResultat.DataSource = null;
            listBoxSökResultat.DataSource = Sökresultat;

        }

        private void listBoxSökResultat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string markerat;


            markerat = listBoxSökResultat.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower();
            if (markerat == null) return;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            if (listBoxSökResultat.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;
            var v = (from x in el.Descendants("recept")
                     where x.Element("namn").Value.ToLower() == markerat
                     select x).FirstOrDefault();

            if (v == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Finns inte!");
                return;
            }

            textBoxNamn.Text = v.Element("namn").Value;
            listBox1.Items.Add(v.Element("portioner").Value);

            var test = v.DescendantsAndSelf("ingrediens").ToList();
            foreach (var item in test)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.Value);
            }

            var test2 = v.DescendantsAndSelf("steg").ToList();
            foreach (var item in test2)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(item.Value);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listBoxSökResultat.SelectedItem` is what is `null`, so any further calls (`.ToString()`) will cause that exception. You are currently checking it's not `null` **and** `SelectedItems` has a `count` higher than `0`, but *after* the problem occurs. By then it's too late. That defensive checking is great, but you are doing it a little too late.

`SelectedItem` will be `null` if there is no selected item at the time, so you should check *that* first:

```
if (listBoxSökResultat.SelectedItem != null)
{
    markerat = listBoxSökResultat.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower();
}
```

That will let you pass *this* particular problem.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. But i used this instead
listBoxSökResultat.SelectedIndexChanged -= listBoxSökResultat_SelectedIndexChanged;

then at the bottom i just used +=